# Xfce and Xscreensaver doesn't seem to consider keyboard activity "activity" - how change?

Tags: xfce, debian

After I upgraded from Debian Squeeze to Wheezy, the combination of Xfce and Xscreensaver doesn't seem to consider keyboard activity to be user activity.

Since I sometimes use only the keyboard for long periods of time, this means that eventually the screensaver activates because of a lack of mouse input. This is somewhat of an annoyance, but another key press (or a bump on the mouse) will cause the screensaver to go away and wait another period of time before kicking in again.

**How do I make the system consider keyboard input to be activity?** I looked at the screensaver preferences but couldn't find anything relevant.

**Alternatively,** how do I switch to a screensaver subsystem which does accept keyboard input as user activity? (All I want is a blank screen screensaver and monitor DPMI suspend and power-off after a configurable delay in X.)

In case it matters, I'm using a USB keyboard hooked directly to the PC (no USB hub in between). The mouse is also USB.

Comment: I switched to `xautolock` & `alock` for similar reasons.

Comment: @frostschutz That sounds interesting; would you be willing to elaborate on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to fix `xscreensaver`. It gave me similar trouble, except it was when watching movies using `mplayer`. Since I couldn't find a solution that worked, I switched to another system entirely.

I use `xautolock` (which detects user inactivity), `alock` (which blanks and locks the screen), and `xeyes` to warn me about the imminent inactivity timeout in case I'm just pondering at some text window or web page.

As an extra feature, `xautolock` is also able to register the position of the mouse cursor. I set it up to lock the screen immediately when the mouse curser goes into the upper left corner of the screen; and to prevent locking when it's in the lower left corner of the screen. So when I watch a movie, I simply move the mouse pointer to the bottom left and the lock will never come up.

Here's the full command I use (to go into your DM's startup scripts):

```
xautolock \
    -time 5 -locker "alock -auth passwd -bg blank" \
    -notify 10 -notifier "killall xeyes; xeyes" \
    -corners +0-0 -cornerdelay 10 -cornerredelay 10 \
    -secure &
```

The monitor also goes into standby for me after the screen is locked for a while, I don't remember if I did any additional configuration for that or if it just worked the way it should by itself...